# Adding class object in stl map as a value

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, insert

I want to add  class object in STL map as a value in C++.It's like `std::map<CString,class myClass*>myMap`. But compilers showing me error in doing this. Should I have to implement all comparison operators overloading for that class?? If not then how do I can achieve that?
Code is as follows:
// header file

```
#pragma once
#include "afxsock.h"
#include"NetworkDataProcessor.h"
#include"MainFrm.h"
#include"ChattingDialog.h"
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class CConnectionManager :public CAsyncSocket
{
public:
    static CConnectionManager *GetClientInstance();
    BOOL ClientSignIn(CString, CString);
    void ConnectToServer();
public:
    CString  m_sendBuffer; 
    int    m_nBytesSent; 
    int   m_nBytesBufferSize = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;
    virtual void OnClose(int nErrorCode);
    virtual void OnConnect(int nErrorCode);
    virtual void OnReceive(int nErrorCode);
    virtual void OnSend(int nErrorCode);
public:

    std::map<CString, CChattingDialog* >ChatWindows;
private:`enter code here`
    CConnectionManager();
    ~CConnectionManager();
    static CConnectionManager * client_instance;
};
```

// cpp file function:

```
void CMyMessangerView::OnClientListClick(NMHDR* pnmh, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    DWORD dwPos = ::GetMessagePos();
    CPoint point((int)LOWORD(dwPos), (int)HIWORD(dwPos)); 
    GetListCtrl().ScreenToClient(&point);  int nIndex; if ((nIndex = GetListCtrl().HitTest(point)) != -1)
    {
    CString string = GetListCtrl().GetItemText(nIndex, 0);
    CChattingDialog chatingDlg;
    chatingDlg.SendToUser = string;
    CString user = chatingDlg.UserRealName(string);
    CConnectionManager *client = CConnectionManager::GetClientInstance();
    client->ChatWindows.insert(pair<CString, CChattingDialog *>(user, &chatingDlg));
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    chatingDlg.DoModal();
    } 
    *pResult = 0;

}
```

ERRORS:
    15  IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=CString, _Ty=CChattingDialog *, _Pr=std::less, _Alloc=std::allocator>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::pair)
            object type is: std::map, std::allocator>

Error   3   error C2976: 'std::map' : too few template arguments    c:\projects\poc\mymessanger\mymessanger\clientconnection.h  25  1   MyMessanger

Error   4   error C2665: 'std::pair::pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types    c:\projects\poc\mymessanger\mymessanger\mymessangerview.cpp 131 1   MyMessanger
    16  IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>::pair [with _Ty1=CString, _Ty2=CChattingDialog &]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (CString, CChattingDialog *)    c:\Projects\POC\MyMessanger\MyMessanger\MyMessangerView.cpp 131 29  MyMessanger
 etc... few more errors like indicating the same

Comment: Show us the code and the exact error message.

Comment: std::map<CString,class myClass*>myMap. "class myClass" looks weird. Why are you adding "class".

Comment: I need collection of this class objects along with key as string. i want to get object of that class according to some string type keys.

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal Other than the syntax error (which still isn't clear which line has the error), you're storing pointers to local variables in the map.  Those variables do not exist outside of the block they're declared in, so this code is faulty: `client->ChatWindows.insert(pair<CString, CChattingDialog *>(user, &chatingDlg)`

Comment: Also, don't post Intellisense errors.  Post compiler errors.

Comment: Pls try this, client->ChatWindows.insert(make_pair(user, &chatingDlg));

Comment: @user1: that doesn't fix the problem PaulMcKenzie's identified... that `chatingDlg` is a local variable.  Mahendra: you need to do something like `CChattingDialog pChatingDlg = new CChattingDialog;` pChatingDlg->SendToUser = string;` etc.. then add pChatingDlg to the `map`.  You should then `delete` the `ChatingDlg`s when they're removed from the `map`, or store them using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and they'll get deleted automatically. Alternatively (but potentially slower) - store the `ChatingDlg` by value, rather than by pointer.

Comment: @Tony D, I agree what you are saying, that local variable is anyway a problem. But what I have not understood is, client->ChatWindows.insert(pair<CString, CChattingDialog *>(user, &chatingDlg) is compiler error. though he is passing address of local var, it is perfectly valid code from syntactic perspective , why compiler error.

Comment: @user1: remember it's an intellisense error not a compiler error - given `std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>::pair [with _Ty1=CString, _Ty2=CChattingDialog &]` I'd say the second type wasn't a pointer at the time intellisense parsed it, then he's edited the code afterwards and the intellisense message is out of date....

Comment: @Mahendra Chhimwal, turn-off intellisense error reporting, Do rebuild your project and paste the full build log here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie.. thanks for pointing the errors..and I will keep remind your advice of not putting Intellisense errors here.

Comment: Now I compile the code by making little bit modification as said by Fomin Arseniy in his answer. Now I am getting errorsError 4 error C2065: 'CChattingDialog' : undeclared identifier Error 3 error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::map' (or there is no acceptable conversion)..Error 5 error C2923: 'std::map' : 'CChattingDialog' is not a valid template type argument for parameter er

Comment: I change the declaration of map as std::map<CString,class CChatingDialog>ChatWindows;    instead of std::map<CString,CChatingDialog>ChatWindows, now it is showing only one error Error 1 error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for responding to this problem. Thank you Fomin Arseniy.
The solution to this problem is what I guessed in the question and Fomin Arseniy said above.
  We must have to overload at least Copy constructor and assigning operator for class we are going to use in map as a value.
First ,map declaration for user defined data types needs to be like

```
std::map<CString, class CChattingDialog> ChatWindows;
```

instead of

```
std::map<CString, CChattingDialog> ChatWindows;
```

and second,I added two functions

```
 CChattingDialog& operator=(const CChattingDialog &s); 

 CChattingDialog(const CChattingDialog &s);
```

in  the class  CChattingDialog . Used inserting method as advised by Fomin Arseniy.

```
client->ChatWindows[user] = &chatingDlg;
```

compiled the code successfully.

We must have to provide  public constructor, copy constructor, desctructor, assining operator and operator< (less than) if need to add user defined data types in STL map.

Answer (score 2):

You use std::map in wrong way. You should rewrite your code as follows:

```
client->ChatWindows[user] = &chatingDlg;
```

(If you want to use map::insert method you can read about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/. There is no pair inserting as you do, there is one method that returns pair of interator/succes).

However, you also asked what do you need to implement in your class to store it in map not by pointer but by value as:

```
std::map<CString, CChattingDialog> ChatWindows;
```

Correct answer is: you need public constructor, copy constructor, desctructor, assining operator and operator< (less than) in class CChattingDialog but not in class CConnectionManager.
Map uses them to have possibility to correctly store, copy, delete and sort elements of this class in it.